# Accessing an object through SQLIte database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, sqlite

I am passing an object to the method in which I am executing a query. My method is:

```
-(BOOL)searchWordInDatabase:(NSString *)string
{
NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory= [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SymbolTalkLanguageElement.sqlite"];

//Open the database
//might have to make database as property
if(sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &dataBase) ==SQLITE_OK)
{
    const char *sql="select ImageName from tblLanguageElement where Category= string";
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if(sqlite3_prepare(dataBase, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]);
            //[list addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]];
            return YES;
        }

    }



}
return NO;
```

}

But I am not getting the value of the String in the query. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mistake in your query. You can not substitute a string like that. Do it in the following way.

```
NSString *sqlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select ImageName from tblLanguageElement where Category = '%@'", string];
char *sql = (char *)[sqlStr UTF8String];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure that your database exists at that path you retrieve.** And you can bind string variables as follows while executing statements.

```
 const char *sql = "select ImageName from tblLanguageElement where Category = ?";
 sqlite3_stmt *statement;
 if(sqlite3_prepare(dataBase, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
 {
      sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [string UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

      while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
      {
           NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]);
           //[list addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]];
        return YES;
      }
 }
```